# Function in a text field onChange doesnt get called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with a TextField (office ui fabric) with an onChange that calls for a function that saves the value in a state. However, this function never get called even if the user inputs a text/value.

My code:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleAttend.bind(this)}>
    <TextField onChange = {(value) => this.setAttendComment(value)}/>
    <PrimaryButton text={strings.EventCardPanelAttendButton} type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>
```

And my `save` function that never gets called (in `onChange`).

```
public setAttendComment (e) { 
    this.setState({ attendComment: e })
};
```

How come? It has never happened to me before.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleAttend.bind(this)}>
    <TextField onChange = {(e) => this.setAttendComment(e.target.value)}/>
    <PrimaryButton text={strings.EventCardPanelAttendButton} type="submit" value="Submit"  />
</form>

public setAttendComment (value) { 
    this.setState({ attendComment: value })
};
```